# View and MVC controller model not getting updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view as below:
[image]

I changed the value to 8000.This data is not getting passed to my model on click of a button.Edit is the method within my controller.When click is invoked even though I changed value the original state of model value 9000 is being returned.I might be missing something really simple.Can you please help identify

Controller Call:
    public ActionResult Edit(Model model)

```
$('#saveall-button').click(function (s) {
        s.preventDefault();

        var ModelData = GetModel();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Controller")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { model: ModelData },
            success: function () {                
                console.log("Successfully saved");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

<script>


         function GetModel() {
            return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        }
```

Comment: can you give the implementation for GetModel() function ?

Comment: please post all the relevant parts of your model, view and controller.

Comment: Well, assuming I'm reading your code correctly, you set `ModelData` **once**, and don't actually modify it - you're `POST`ing the _same/original data_

Comment: Post your MVC code too .

Comment: EdsF yes you are right. I was looking for a way to get the UI updates in javascript